# Running tests with xcodebuild often results in a "Test process crashed" since Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, xcodebuild

We are running xcodebuild on our CI system (jenkins, setup as a slave on a mac mini). We've been running this for the last year without any trouble. However, since we updated to Xcode 6.1.1, the build has been unstable. About 50% of our builds fail, reporting:

```
Testing failed:
    testXYZ encountered an error (Test process crashed)
```

The failing test is different every time, so this seems to us like a problem related to the tooling, and not so much our tests.

To be complete, this is the command we use to run our tests:

```
xcodebuild -verbose -workspace our.xcworkspace \
    -scheme OurScheme \
    -destination="platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone Retina (4-inch),OS=7.1" \
    -configuration Debug \
    -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES clean build test
```

Running the process manually on the CI machine seems to be less dodgy. Are there any new requirements since Xcode 6 that we are missing?

=============== EDIT

After some more research we changed the "destination" command line option from:

```
-destination="platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone Retina (4-inch),OS=7.1"
```

to:

```
-destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 4s,OS=7.1"
```

Mark two differences here:

- the equal sign that needs to be removed. The destination was basically ignored, and resulted in the simulator being started with a default (iPhone 4s, iOS 7.0.3 in our case).
- the name had to be changed to iPhone 4s. Apparently the device names were changed between Xcode 5 and 6. If you want to check what the device names are, have a look under Window > Devices.

While this doesn't solve the actual crashes on 7.0.3, we are now able to run a stable build on 7.1 and above.